# Existe um nome especial para palavras que admitem o sufixo "dade"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, classificação-de-palavras, sufixos

Em matemática, "função injetora" tem exatamente o mesmo significado de "função injetiva". Conforme destacado [neste texto](http://www2.ime.unicamp.br/~ma225/texto8.pdf), é preferível usar a segunda opção porque ela admite a derivação "injetividade" enquanto "injetoridade" não existe. Em face disso, gostaria de saber:

1. Em geral, existe algum termo que podemos usar para nos referirmos a palavras que admitem sufixos?
2. Em particular, existe algum termo utilizado para distinguir palavras que admitem o sufixo "dade" daquelas que não admitem? Ou seja, as palavras que admitem o sufixo "dade" (como, por exemplo, "injetivo") pertencem a alguma "classe especial" de palavras?
3. O processo de transformar uma palavra adicionando o sufixo "dade" possui algum nome específico?
4. É correto dizer que a apalavra "injetor" não admite sufixação?

Answer (score 3):

O sufixo “dade” é usado para formar substantivos (femininos) abstratos derivados de adjetivos.

Vem do latim -tas, tatis (-tate em latim vulgar). Existe em línguas românicas (italiano “tà”, francês “té”, espanhol “dad” (ou “tad”), português “dade” (“tade”), romeno “tate”) e até em inglês “i/ety”.

Os substantivos assim formados expressam a idéia de estado, situação ou quantidade.